# Python Keyboard calls on_press_key() already since I have to hit 'Enter' to run the python from terminal

Tags: python, keyboard

I know that for some reason it takes the input from executing the python programm but I don't know how to resolve this. Using another key isn't an option since I want the user to be able to login without having to push the login button.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import mysql.connector
import sys
import keyboard
import main_window

class login_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Wochenbericht")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r"src/schreibfeder.png"))
        self.setObjectName("login_window")
        self.setMinimumSize(300,300)
        self.setMaximumSize(300,300)

        main_layout = QGridLayout()
        login_fields = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(login_fields,0,0)
        button_fields = QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(button_fields,1,0)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        #FIELDS FOR THE LOGIN
        self.username = QLineEdit(self)
        self.username.setObjectName("username_field")
        self.password = QLineEdit(self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
        self.password.setObjectName("password_field")

        login_fields.addWidget(self.username)
        login_fields.addWidget(self.password)

        #BUTTONS FOR THE LOGIN
        login_btn = QPushButton(self)
        login_btn.setText("Login")
        login_btn.clicked.connect(self.check_in)
        cancel_btn = QPushButton(self)
        cancel_btn.setText("Abbrechen")
        cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.cancel)

        button_fields.addWidget(login_btn)
        button_fields.addWidget(cancel_btn)

        keyboard.on_press_key("enter",self.enter_pressed())
        

    #*********************************************** PYSLOTS ********************************************************************
    #****************************************************************************************************************************
    def cancel(self) :
        self.close()
    
    def check_in(self):
        username = self.username.text()
        key = self.password.text()

        try:
            connector = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = username,
            password = key,
            database = 'berichte'
            )
            self.close()
            self.tb_window = main_window.main_window(connector)
            self.tb_window.show()    
        except mysql.connector.Error as e :
            if e.errno == 1045:
                warning_message = QMessageBox(self)
                warning_message.setText("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen: Nutzername oder Passwort stimmen nicht überin")
                warning_message.show()
            else :
                print(f"Error: {e}")
    def enter_pressed(self):
        self.check_in()
```

I need the first input to be ignored when the application isn't running. Or else it already raises an error.

Comment: Use `self.password.returnPressed.connect(self.check_in)` instead of trying to detect it manually. [Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QLineEdit.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.returnPressed)

Comment: this question is not an MRE : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , please delete part of code not needed

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).